# Upload de arquivo automático

Tags: php

Preciso fazer com que ao atualizar a pagina, o meu elemento `<input type="file">` já venha carregado com os arquivos que serão salvos no banco, lembrando que os arquivos terão o mesmo nome.

Comment: Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) [Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1630/7210

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor o problema, dar exemplo com um trecho de código ou algo do tipo? Não deu para entender do que se trata o problema, só da para entender que tem a ver com upload. Mas quer carregar o que os arquivos? mostrar os uploads que você já vez e salvou no banco etc....

Comment: Se o que precisa fora referente a upload você pode carregar apenas links indicando o que já foi carregado e usando o input file apenas para enviar novos arquivos. Existem um componente que pode ser útil no caso de upload http://www.dropzonejs.com/, pode ser configurado para exibir os downloads que foram feitos com sucesso além de diversas outras funcionalidades. Contudo o ideal seria mesmo editar sua pergunta para deixar mais clara sua necessidade.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer que o formulário seja auto-submetido? Se for isto:

```
<form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" onchange="formulario.sumbit()" name="arquivos[]" multiple/>
</form>
```

A mágica está no `onchange="formulario.submit()"`. Ele executa a função quando o valor do `input` for alterado.

O atributo `name` com `[]` no final servem para facilidade na hora de tratar os dados no *backend*.

O atributo `multiple` serve para dizer ao navegador aceitar vários arquivos.

Answer (score 0):

O campo input type=file não pode ser carregado novamente com os arquivos que estão no banco, você deve exibir os arquivos de outra forma. o campo do tipo file não é como um campo do tipo text que você pode adicionar o texto em um value para exibir ao usuário.

Por exemplo: Você carregou uma imagem no input file, enviou para o banco. No seu banco vc salvou o caminho da imagem que foi feito upload no servidor. Na hora de editar essa imagem vc não carrega os dados dela no seu input file, vc exibe ela em um  o campo input file fica em branco.

Answer (score 0):

Formulários com eventos e uploads (simples ou múltiplos) são um problema do ponto de vista de usabilidade.

Devido a restrições de segurança, você não pode definir o nome do arquivo a ser enviado programaticamente. Então, se for necessário atualizar o form sem Ajax, o arquivo será enviado ou "perdido".

Então, o que geralmente eu faço é desvincular o envio de anexos do restante do formulário:

1. O primeiro passo é fazer o upload automático quando o usuário seleciona um arquivo. O arquivo é gravado num local temporário e vinculado à sessão do usuário com algum identificador relacionado ao formulário atual.
2. Após o envio, eu atualizo o formulário mostrando um item com o nome do arquivo e uma opção para removê-lo. O(s) arquivo(s) já enviados devem ser listados através dos itens salvos como descrito no item anterior.
3. Quando o formulário for efetivamente submetido eu verifico se há um ou mais arquivos "temporários", incluindo suas informações em alguma tabela do modelo e movendo os arquivos para o diretório definitivo.

O diretório com arquivos temporários deve ser limpo de tempos em tempos, excluindo os arquivos de sessões abandonadas. Pode-se utilizar algum critério relacionado à data do arquivo para isso, por exemplo, excluindo arquivos mais antigos que 1 dia.